# Does CLLocation course compute direction of your device or movement speed?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5

Say I walk sideways to the east while my iPhone aims to the north. Will course property of locationManager.location.course shows that I am heading east or north?

Not clear from the documentation.

Also does startUpdatingHeading uses GPS? If not, why it's handled by CLLocationManager?

Answer (score 3):

If you walk to the east while your phone aims north, the *course* will return *east* and the *heading* will return *north*. These two pieces of information are provided by different pieces of hardware (which is why they are activated separately and may not be available on all devices); from Apple's [Location Awareness Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/GettingHeadings/GettingHeadings.html):

> Core Location supports two different ways to get direction-related
>   information:
>
> - Devices with a magnetometer can report the direction in which a    device is pointing, also known as its **heading**.
> - Devices with GPS    hardware can report the direction in which a device is moving, also    known as its **course**.
>
> Remember that heading and course information do not represent the same
>   information. The heading of a device reflects the actual orientation
>   of the device relative to true north or magnetic north. The course of
>   the device represents the direction of travel and does not take into
>   account the device orientation.